# Unit Testing Zend Framework 3 Album App

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, zend-framework3

I want to unit test album app implementation present on zend framework 3 tutorial page. I aded some functionality(login and acl) to the original implementation.I followed the tutorial for unit testing zf3,but unable to follow it,how to mock authentication and write some more test cases.Any Help is appreciated.Some piece of code from my album app implementation.

[Unit Testing Tutotial for zf3](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/unit-testing/)

**AlbumController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Album\Controller;

use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Album\Model\LoginTable;
use Album\Controller\LoginController;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Album\Form\AlbumForm;
use Album\Model\Album;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator as paginatorIterator;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Album\Form\SearchForm;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Album\Utility\Acl;
use \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
  private $table;
  protected $role;
  public function __construct(AlbumTable $table){
     $this->table = $table;
 } 

 public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
 {
   $userSession = new Container('user');
   if (!isset($userSession->email)) {
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
 }else {
    $this->role = $userSession->role;
    parent::onDispatch($e);
 }
}
 public function authorize($role,$action)
{
   if($role == 'admin'){
     $acl = new Acl();
     if ($acl->isAllowed('admin', 'AlbumController', $action)) {
       return true;
    }
 }
  return false;
}

 public function indexAction(){
    $searchform = new SearchForm();
    $searchform->get('submit')->setValue('search');
    $select = new Select();
    $order_by = $this->params()->fromRoute('order_by') ?$this->params()->fromRoute('order_by') : 'id';
    $search="";
    $order = $this->params()->fromRoute('order') ?$this->params()->fromRoute('order') : Select::ORDER_ASCENDING;
    $page = $this->params()->fromRoute('page') ? (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('page') : 1;
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isGet())
    {
      $formdata    = (array) $request->getQuery();
      $search_data = array();
      foreach ($formdata as $key => $value)
      {
        if ($key != 'submit')
       {
         if (!empty($value))
         {
          $search_data[$key] = $value;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!empty($search_data))
    {
      $search = $search_data;
    }
    $searchform->setData($formdata);
  }
  $search_by = $this->params()->fromQuery() ? $this->params()->fromQuery() : '';
  $paginator = $this->table->fetchAll($order_by,$order,$search,$select);
        $page = (int) $this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1);
        $page = ($page < 1) ? 1 : $page;
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
        return new ViewModel([
    'search_by'=> $search_by,
    'order_by' => $order_by,
    'order' => $order,
    'page' => $page,
    'paginator' => $paginator,
    'pageAction' => 'album',
    'form'       => $searchform,
    'flashMessages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages(),
    ]);
}
 public function addAction()
{
  $action = 'add';
  $permission = $this->authorize($this->role,$action);
  if (!$permission) {
     $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>You dont have the privilege to add!!</b></div>');
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}

$form = new AlbumForm();
$form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');
$request = $this->getRequest();

if ($request->isPost()) {
  $album = new Album();
  $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
  $form->setData($request->getPost());
  $add = $request->getPost('submit', 'Cancel');

  if($add == 'Cancel'){
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>Cancelled by User...!!</b></div>');
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
  }

  if ($form->isValid()) {
    $album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
    $this->table->saveAlbum($album);
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Added Successfully...</b></div>');
  }else {
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>Failed to Add...!!</b></div>');
    return array('form' => $form);
  }
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}
return array('form' => $form);
}

 public function editAction()
{
  $action = 'edit';
  $permission = $this->authorize($this->role,$action);
  if (!$permission) {
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>You dont have the privilege to edit!!</b></div>');
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

if (0 === $id) {
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', ['action' => 'add']);
}
try {
  $album = $this->table->getAlbum($id);
}catch (\Exception $e) {
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', ['action' => 'index']);
}

$form = new AlbumForm();
$form->bind($album);
$form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

$request = $this->getRequest();
$viewData = ['id' => $id, 'form' => $form];

if (! $request->isPost()) {
  return $viewData;
}

$form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
$form->setData($request->getPost());
$edit = $request->getPost('submit', 'Cancel');

if($edit == 'Cancel'){
  $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>Cancelled by User...!!</b></div>');
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}

if (! $form->isValid()) {
  $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>Failed to Update...!!</b></div>');
  return $viewData;
}else{
  $this->table->saveAlbum($album);
  $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Record Updated Successfully...!!</b></div>');
}
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', ['action' => 'index']);
}

public function deleteAction()
{
 $action = 'delete';
$permission = $this->authorize($this->role,$action);
if (!$permission) {
  $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>You dont have the privilege to delete!!</b></div>');
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}

$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
if (!$id) {
 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
 $del = $request->getPost('del', 'No');
if ($del == 'Yes') {
  $id = (int) $request->getPost('id');
  $this->table->deleteAlbum($id);
  $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Record Deleted Successfully...!!</b></div>');
 }else{
  $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>Failed to delete...!!</b></div>');
}
 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}
return [
  'id'    => $id,
  'album' => $this->table->getAlbum($id),
 ];
 }
}
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Album\Controller;

use Album\Form\LoginForm;
use Album\Model\Login;
use Album\Model\LoginTable;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Result;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public $userSession;
    public $loginTable;
    public function __construct(LoginTable $loginTable)
    {
      $this->loginTable = $loginTable;
    }
 public function loginAction()
 {
    $userSession = new Container('user');
    if(!isset($userSession->email)){
    $form = new LoginForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Login');

    $request = $this->getRequest();

     if ($request->isPost()){
       $login = new Login();
       $form->setInputFilter($login->getInputFilter());
       $form->setData($request->getPost());
       if ($form->isValid())
       {
         $data=$form->getData();
         $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(array(
           'driver'         => 'Pdo',
           'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=customers;host=localhost;',
           'username' => "root",
           'password' => "",
         ));

            $authAdapter=new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,'login','email','password');
                  $authAdapter->setTableName('login')->setIdentityColumn('email')->setCredentialColumn('password');
                  $authAdapter->setIdentity($data['email'])->setCredential($data['password']);
            $auth=new AuthenticationService();
            $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
            switch ($result->getCode())
                        {
                  case Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND:
                    break;
                  case Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID:
                                break;
                  case Result::SUCCESS:
                    $userSession->email = $data['email'];
                    $row=$this->loginTable->getRow($userSession->email);
                    $userSession->role = $row['role'];
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Login Successful!!</b></div>');
                                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array('action' => 'index'));
                  default :
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
                    break;
            }
         }
     }
     return array('form' => $form,'fm' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages(),);
    }
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}

public function logoutAction(){
    $session = new Container('User');
    $session->getManager()->destroy();
    $auth=new AuthenticationService();
      $auth->clearIdentity();
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ZF has a servicemanger which you can use for dependency injection. You are already using it since you are injecting the UserTable and LoginTable into the controllers. The main reasons to inject objects into controllers and other services is re-usability and testability. Those 2 injected services can easily be mocked and the mocked versions can be injected into those classes during tests.

All the objects that you instantiate inside the controller or in its actions can't be mocked. So you want to refactor and take out the ACL, User session container and AuthenticationService. Write factories for those if needed and add those to the servicemanger. Finally inject them where needed into the controllers. Now you can mock them or write individual tests for each component.

Next issue is building queries inside the controller creating a database connection. Again, creating the database connection would go into a factory so you can reuse it and inject it where needed. Building the query would go into a [repository](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/in-depth-guide/models-and-servicemanager/). Als the username and password should go into a local configuration file (one that is ignored by git).

ZendFramework has [multiple packages](https://docs.zendframework.com/) to help you with this:

- https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-authentication/intro/
- https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc-plugin-identity/
- https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-paginator/intro/